# Wrapping boost::chrono timing mechanism into class compilation errors?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, c++-chrono

The problem I have pertains to the declaration of the resulting type of an operation between to similar types written as `t1_t0 = t1 - t0;` in a.cpp. `t1` and `t0` are the final and initial times respectively with the difference being used to measure the time span between one calculation. I tried using `auto` all over the function in place of the variables `boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point`, `std::chrono::seconds` and `int` but that caused strange problems with declaring variables after the fact that the function was called before it.

It was called the `error: use of  before deduction of ‘auto’` compilation error so I then tried to compile the project using the real types and now I have this trouble. The project does compile fine (using `auto`) if the class is declared above `int main` **but it doesn't work if the class is separated into header and cpp files**.

Here's the whole project, please help!

```
#include <iostream>
#include "a.h"

int main()
{
    a A;

    int timer = A.time();
    std::cout<<timer<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

this is a.h

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/chrono/chrono_io.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>
#include <boost/thread/thread.hpp>
#include <sstream>
#include <cassert>
#include <chrono>

class a
{
    private:

    public:

    a();
    ~a();
    int time();
};
#endif
```

this is the a.cpp

```
#include "a.h"

a::a(){}
a::~a(){}
int a::time()//simple benchmark timer
{
    boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t0, t1, t1_t0;
    t0 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    //Run a process to measure time.

    t1 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    t1_t0 = t1 - t0;//Not sure what the resulting type is here?

    std::chrono::seconds nsec = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(t1_t0);
    //Not sure what the resulting type is here?

    return nsec.count();//Not sure what the return type is here?
}
```

Here are the errors compiling it.

```
||=== Build: Debug in return_type_auto_from_class (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
/home/Desktop/a.cpp||In member function ‘int a::time()’:|
/home/Desktop/a.cpp|14|error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘boost::chrono::steady_clock::time_point {aka boost::chrono::time_point<boost::chrono::steady_clock>}’ and ‘boost::common_type<boost::chrono::duration<long int, boost::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> >, boost::chrono::duration<long int, boost::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >::type {aka boost::chrono::duration<long int, boost::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> >}’)|
/usr/include/boost/chrono/time_point.hpp|156|note: candidate: constexpr boost::chrono::time_point<boost::chrono::steady_clock>& boost::chrono::time_point<boost::chrono::steady_clock>::operator=(const boost::chrono::time_point<boost::chrono::steady_clock>&)|
/usr/include/boost/chrono/time_point.hpp|156|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘boost::common_type<boost::chrono::duration<long int, boost::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> >, boost::chrono::duration<long int, boost::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >::type {aka boost::chrono::duration<long int, boost::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> >}’ to ‘const boost::chrono::time_point<boost::chrono::steady_clock>&’|
/usr/include/boost/chrono/time_point.hpp|156|note: candidate: constexpr boost::chrono::time_point<boost::chrono::steady_clock>& boost::chrono::time_point<boost::chrono::steady_clock>::operator=(boost::chrono::time_point<boost::chrono::steady_clock>&&)|
/usr/include/boost/chrono/time_point.hpp|156|note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘boost::common_type<boost::chrono::duration<long int, boost::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> >, boost::chrono::duration<long int, boost::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> > >::type {aka boost::chrono::duration<long int, boost::ratio<1l, 1000000000l> >}’ to ‘boost::chrono::time_point<boost::chrono::steady_clock>&&’|
/home/Desktop/a.cpp|16|error: no matching function for call to ‘duration_cast(boost::chrono::steady_clock::time_point&)’|
/usr/include/c++/5/chrono|194|note: candidate: template<class _ToDur, class _Rep, class _Period> constexpr typename std::enable_if<std::chrono::__is_duration<_Tp>::value, _ToDur>::type std::chrono::duration_cast(const std::chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>&)|
/usr/include/c++/5/chrono|194|note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:|
/home/Desktop/a.cpp|16|note:   ‘boost::chrono::steady_clock::time_point {aka boost::chrono::time_point<boost::chrono::steady_clock>}’ is not derived from ‘const std::chrono::duration<_Rep, _Period>’|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 2 second(s)) ===|
```

Edited code, this does fix the original and it works now.

```
int a::time()
{
    boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t0, t1;//, t1_t0;
    t0 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    //Run a process to measure time.
    boost::this_thread::sleep_for( boost::chrono::milliseconds{ 2000});

    t1 = boost::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

    auto t1_t0 = t1 - t0;

    auto nsec = boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::seconds>(t1_t0);

    return nsec.count();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't mix `boost::chrono` and `std::chrono`.  Use one or the other.  I recommend `std::chrono` if it is supplied and supported by your platform, else use `boost::chrono`.
2. The difference between two `time_point`s is a `duration`, not another `time_point`.  For example "tomorrow" and "today" can be thought of as time points (with a very coarse precision).  `tomorrow - today == 1 day`.  A day is a duration.
3. If you want the final result as nanoseconds, no need to try so hard:

   `nanoseconds nsec = t1 - t0;`
4. How about returning `nanoseconds` instead of `int` from `a::time()`?  That way the client has a type-safe duration instead of an `int` that could mean anything at all.

   `return t1 - t0;`

Comment: 1. Helped me compile it!. 2. What is the boost type for the duration though?

Comment: Nevermind `nanoseconds` is a variable type in boost? 4. I'll change it.

Comment: I tried changing the return type from `int` to `nanoseconds` and that didn't work. If you could post your code that's fine. The code with the fix above does compile and it works!

Comment: Oh, I got fooled by the variable name `nsec`.  It looks like you want your units to be seconds, right?

Comment: Right, seconds, but I still don't see what the boost type is for nanoseconds, seconds, etc.

Comment: You could make your return type `boost::chrono::seconds`, and then you don't need to add the `.count()` on your `return`.  And then the client of `timer` knows he has seconds (as opposed to some other unit like nanoseconds).  That's optional.  If you really want to return `int`, that's fine too.